# How can I restore Media Apps, Internet Apps, More Apps, Find File part of Unity Dash?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, unity, unity-dash

People, this happened on Ubuntu 11.04, and Ubuntu 11.10 in twice I have reinstalled ubuntu,unity,gdm,lighdm and etc... Sometimes is and process with I close with the options to search in the unity dock just disappeared, options that disappeared is: App internet, More App, App midia. 
What I do to arrive that back?

Comment: Me no Understand anything

Answer (score 1):

Down towards the bottom of the Dash you should see 4 Icons.

Select the one that looks like a house, and you should then have the Items you're looking for!

[image: Unity Dash Screen Shot]